# jquery tagsinput and ui autocomplete: can they work with pre-loaded source?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, jquery-tags-input

I have a little trouble. There's working code with tagsinput, and I know how to work with autocomplete from jquery ui.

[code exampe](http://jsfiddle.net/Bandydan/kV8yn/1/)

Neither

```
autocomplete' :{
    'source': tags_array
}
```

Nor

```
$("#new_tags_tagsinput").autocomplete({source: tags_array});
```

Seems to work.

On [tagsinput site](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input) there's an example, which requires autocomplete URL, but I'd like to use loaded array, like it is on autocomplete example. I tried different options, no one worked. Is there such a way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Initialize it like this:

```
var tags_array = ["lorem", "ipsum", "dolar", "sit", "amet"];
$("#new_tags").tagsInput({
    'defaultText':'add...',
    'height':'100px',
    'width':'300px',
    'autocomplete_url': '',
    'autocomplete' :{
        'source': tags_array
    }
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y3jEH/).

Explanation: first, as you use that array of tags as a source, there's no need to keep the same structure (i.e., comma-delimited string) - it's easier to work with a plain array from the beginning.

Second, as [the source code of the plugin](https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input/blob/master/jquery.tagsinput.js) shows, `autocomplete_url` is the setting really defining whether or not `autocomplete` will be utilized:

```
if (settings.autocomplete_url != undefined) {
  autocomplete_options = {source: settings.autocomplete_url};
  for (attrname in settings.autocomplete) {
    autocomplete_options[attrname] = settings.autocomplete[attrname];
  }
  ...
}
```

In other words, you need to specify something other than `null` or `undefined` in `autocomplete_url` param to make it use that jQuery UI plugin. Actually, it might be a good idea for that plugin to check that param type - and setting up the `autocomplete` source option accordingly.

Comment: Long Live @raina77ow !